# How to prove that f is a polynomial and, if f is injective, then f is of degree 1 in complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis

prereq: $f :\Bbb C \longrightarrow\Bbb C$ holomorphic with:
$f$ is injective or $\lim |f(z)| = \infty$ for $|z|\to\infty$.

Show: $f$ is a polynomial and, if $f$ is injective, then $f$ is of degree $1$.

Hint: Consider the holomorphic function $z\mapsto f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$ in the punctured disc.

I proved it [the following way (included picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GISiN.jpg), but I'm not sure whether that's enough to prove the statement.

Comment: How may zeros does a polynomial of degree $n$ have?

Comment: maximum n zeroes